# Google and Facebook social login - does sub change?

Tags: facebook, oauth, google-plus, single-sign-on, oauth-2.0

I have implemented external logins to my identitiy solution and use the provided sub as identifier. Lately i noticed that the sub of my social user changed.

Is this a failure on my site or does the provided sub from Facebook and Google change over time?

Comment: What do you mean by “sub”? (Facebook introduced _app-scoped user ids_ with API v2.0, but I think that should be common knowledge by now.)

Comment: With sub I mean the user identifier claim. I know that it's app-scoped but still i assumed that the scoped user id is persistent in the app-scope?

Comment: The app-scoped user id will stay the same, yes.

Comment: Could be a bug somewhere modifying the sub. I'll have to look in to the issue.

Comment: Make sure to handle FB user ids as strings, not as integers. (They can easily be larger than the max integer value on some systems, and when they are converted to float, they loose “precision”, which is something you definitively don’t want with a user id.)